# Is a question about variable scope on a low-code platform appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

#### Background

I am working on a new business process management platform called [Oracle Process Cloud service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/process-cloud/index.html) (often referred to as PCS). The platform is built on top of Oracle's Unified BPM Suite and provides an enhanced composer view (for anyone familiar with Unified BPM) where you can build user interfaces, process models, business rules, business models, RESTful and SOAP integrations and services, et cetera, with little code.

#### The Issue

I am stuck on a particular issue that is not answered anywhere on the Internet, but it has been asked a few times on Oracle's product specific board. The product offers a very robust [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) API that you can leverage within your forms (GUIs) for various reasons. I want to use a particular web service related to the forms attachments, however in order to do that I need to somehow expose either a system attribute or some data object attribute to the form (to pass in to the web service as a template parameter).

#### My Question

Is this appropriate for Stack Overflow? It is very likely that exposing this variable to the form is not a programmatic issue but possibly a platform related configuration. To complicate matters a bit; the type of form I want to use does not let you write JavaScript. You instead just use a native expression syntax. A different type of form does however let you use JavaScript. So my question might also reference the second type of form in case it's impossible with the first one (although I'm confident it's not).

Additionally, it's very likely that a PCS question has never been asked on Stack Overflow. This could very well be due to the newness of the platform. It wouldn't be unrealistic to post it under the [oracle-bpm-soa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-bpm-soa) *(new tag)*, [oracle-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-cloud) *(new tag)* and [oracle-jet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-jet) *(91 questions)* tags though.

I haven't been able to find a clear rule addressing quasi-programming related questions.

Comment: I think it would be OK under the general conditions (has an appropriate problem description, contains a [MCVE], etc.). But don't have too high hopes that it gets very much attention, if that's really such a brandnew niche as you describe. As for the tags simply use [tag:oracle].

Comment: I took the liberty of linking to the documentation site for the software.There does seem to be a massive amount for such a quasi-programming environment, so be sure to read that and make sure your question isn't already answered there. Otherwise, it seems like it would be on topic to ask, but as @TheDude says, you're unlikely to get much attention to it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've read through the docs several times, asked on the Oracle forums, etc.  PCS is essentially just a SlaaS version of oracle-bpm-suite (their SOA product). That product has a long history in the Java community so I'm hoping that crossover is big enough.

Comment: Why should it not be appropriate? It seems to be about programming to me.

Comment: I thought it might be frowned upon due to the fact it could be a configuration issue.  Either way I've spent 3 days on this and it seems like consensus is OK  so I'm going to post it

Comment: What is a *"low-code platform"*?

Comment: A 2018 buzz word for enterprise platforms (BPM, digital experience, portal, etc) with enhanced configuration capabilities used to eliminate the need to code things like user interfaces, integrations, etc.  Some other examples are mulesoft, appian, etc. They've been around forever it's just a new name. Many are just spins on traditional platforms. For example PCS is a web interface configurators sitting on top of Oracle BPM and weblogic server.  I don't generally think they speed up development, but the business thinks otherwise

Comment: @TheDude Do not just use [oracle] unless it specifically related to Oracle RDBMS - the tag description is very clear that you should not just randomly tag everything Oracle owns with [oracle]. If it is another application/service that happens to be developed by Oracle then use the appropriate tag for that application/service and if there is not an appropriate tag then create one.

Comment: The most appropriate tag is oracle-bpm-suite since PCS is BPM Suite with a web interface, and the question is pertinent (and answer may be the same) in both

Comment: This question sounds much more like spam than anything else to me. Noone cares what the platforms offers or what it does, only you, who are facing the problem

Comment: If the question is in regards to the appropriateness of a low code platform question, would you not need to know the context to decide?